# Why my callback is not invoking in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Below is my Tensorflow and Python code which will end the training when accuracy in 99% with the call back function. But the callback is not invoking. Where is the problem ?

```
def train_mnist():

    class myCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
        def on_epoc_end(self, epoch,logs={}):
            if (logs.get('accuracy')>0.99):
                print("Reached 99% accuracy so cancelling training!")
                self.model.stop_training=True



    mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

    (x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data(path=path)

    x_train= x_train/255.0
    x_test= x_test/255.0
    callbacks=myCallback()

    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        # YOUR CODE SHOULD START HERE
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation=tf.nn.relu),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)

    ])

    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    # model fitting
    history = model.fit(x_train,y_train, epochs=10,callbacks=[callbacks]) 
    # model fitting
    return history.epoch, history.history['acc'][-1]
```

Comment: Because of a typo: it's `epoch` not `epoc` (i.e. look at the name of method in your custom callback).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're misspelling epoch and also you should return `accuracy` not `acc`.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Add, Activation, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, Sequential
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import random


from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Input, GaussianNoise, BatchNormalization

def train_mnist():
  class myCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
      def on_epoch_end(self, epoch,logs={}):
          print(logs.get('accuracy'))
          if (logs.get('accuracy')>0.9):
              print("Reached 90% accuracy so cancelling training!")
              self.model.stop_training=True



  mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

  (x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

  x_train= x_train/255.0
  x_test= x_test/255.0

  callbacks=myCallback()

  model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
      # YOUR CODE SHOULD START HERE
      tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation=tf.nn.relu),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)

  ])

  model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                metrics=['accuracy'])

  # model fitting
  history = model.fit(x_train,y_train, epochs=10,callbacks=[callbacks]) 
  # model fitting
  return history.epoch, history.history['accuracy'][-1]

train_mnist()
```

```
Epoch 1/10
1859/1875 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.2273 - accuracy: 0.93580.93586665391922
Reached 90% accuracy so cancelling training!
1875/1875 [==============================] - 3s 2ms/step - loss: 0.2265 - accuracy: 0.9359

([0], 0.93586665391922)
```

Comment: Please don't provide answers for issues caused by typos. They don't provide any value (and may be considered as rep farming). Instead use "flag" button, then choose "A community specific reason" and then vote for "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". You may choose to leave a comment on the question so that the OP knows what the typos are. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, I didn't know that. Thanks for the advice, I already ran the code and found two bugs so decided to answer anyway. But will definitely keep in mind in the future.

Comment: But it's weird that Keras doesn't throw any warnings when someone tries to implement a random function inside callback without any context.

Comment: That's not relevant to Keras. It's how Python works: there is no fixed template for allowed methods in a Python class. And it's for good: you can decide to implement a helper method in your callback which may not be directly used by Keras; rather it may be called by other methods in the class.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately don't have enough reputation to provide commentary on one of the above comments, but I wanted to point out that the on_epoch_end function is something called directly through tensorflow when an epoch ends. In this case, we're just implementing it inside a custom python class that will be called automatically by the underlying framework. I'm sourcing from Tensorflow in Practice deeplearning.ai week 2 on coursera. Very similar where the issues with the above callback are coming from it seems.

Here's some proof from my most recent run:

```
Epoch 1/20
59968/60000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0648 - acc: 0.9491Inside callback
60000/60000 [==============================] - 34s 575us/sample - loss: 1.0645 - acc: 0.9491
Epoch 2/20
59968/60000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0560 - acc: 0.9825Inside callback
60000/60000 [==============================] - 35s 583us/sample - loss: 0.0560 - acc: 0.9825
Epoch 3/20
59840/60000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0457 - acc: 0.9861Inside callback
60000/60000 [==============================] - 31s 512us/sample - loss: 0.0457 - acc: 0.9861
Epoch 4/20
59840/60000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0428 - acc: 0.9873Inside callback
60000/60000 [==============================] - 32s 528us/sample - loss: 0.0428 - acc: 0.9873
Epoch 5/20
59808/60000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0314 - acc: 0.9909Inside callback
60000/60000 [==============================] - 30s 507us/sample - loss: 0.0315 - acc: 0.9909
Epoch 6/20
59840/60000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0271 - acc: 0.9924Inside callback
60000/60000 [==============================] - 32s 532us/sample - loss: 0.0270 - acc: 0.9924
Epoch 7/20
59968/60000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0238 - acc: 0.9938Inside callback
60000/60000 [==============================] - 33s 555us/sample - loss: 0.0238 - acc: 0.9938
Epoch 8/20
59936/60000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0255 - acc: 0.9934Inside callback
60000/60000 [==============================] - 33s 550us/sample - loss: 0.0255 - acc: 0.9934
Epoch 9/20
59872/60000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0195 - acc: 0.9953Inside callback
60000/60000 [==============================] - 33s 557us/sample - loss: 0.0194 - acc: 0.9953
Epoch 10/20
59744/60000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0186 - acc: 0.9959Inside callback
60000/60000 [==============================] - 33s 551us/sample - loss: 0.0185 - acc: 0.9959
Epoch 11/20
59968/60000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0219 - acc: 0.9954Inside callback
60000/60000 [==============================] - 32s 530us/sample - loss: 0.0219 - acc: 0.9954
Epoch 12/20
59936/60000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0208 - acc: 0.9960Inside callback
60000/60000 [==============================] - 33s 558us/sample - loss: 0.0208 - acc: 0.9960
Epoch 13/20
59872/60000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0185 - acc: 0.9968Inside callback
60000/60000 [==============================] - 31s 520us/sample - loss: 0.0184 - acc: 0.9968
Epoch 14/20
59872/60000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0181 - acc: 0.9970Inside callback
60000/60000 [==============================] - 35s 587us/sample - loss: 0.0181 - acc: 0.9970
Epoch 15/20
59936/60000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0193 - acc: 0.9971Inside callback
60000/60000 [==============================] - 33s 555us/sample - loss: 0.0192 - acc: 0.9972
Epoch 16/20
59968/60000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0176 - acc: 0.9972Inside callback
60000/60000 [==============================] - 33s 558us/sample - loss: 0.0176 - acc: 0.9972
Epoch 17/20
59968/60000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0183 - acc: 0.9974Inside callback
60000/60000 [==============================] - 33s 555us/sample - loss: 0.0182 - acc: 0.9974
Epoch 18/20
59872/60000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0225 - acc: 0.9970Inside callback
60000/60000 [==============================] - 34s 570us/sample - loss: 0.0224 - acc: 0.9970
Epoch 19/20
59808/60000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0185 - acc: 0.9975Inside callback
60000/60000 [==============================] - 33s 548us/sample - loss: 0.0185 - acc: 0.9975
Epoch 20/20
59776/60000 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0150 - acc: 0.9979Inside callback
60000/60000 [==============================] - 34s 565us/sample - loss: 0.0149 - acc: 0.9979
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-1ff3c304aec3> in <module>
----> 1 _, _ = train_mnist_conv()

<ipython-input-24-b469df35dac0> in train_mnist_conv()
     38     )
     39     # model fitting
---> 40     return history.epoch, history.history['accuracy'][-1]
     41 

KeyError: 'accuracy'
```

The key error is because of the history object not having the keyword 'accuracy', so I wanted to address that as a source of  concern before continuing on.